# sqlite3 macOS Sierra

Tags: node.js, macos, npm, sqlite

Every single time I try to install sqlite3 in my mac, I get this error:

```
sh: node-pre-gyp: command not found

npm WARN quiz@1.0.0 No repository field.



npm ERR! file sh

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE

npm ERR! errno ENOENT

npm ERR! syscall spawn

npm ERR! sqlite3@3.1.13 install: `node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build`

npm ERR! spawn ENOENT

npm ERR! 

npm ERR! Failed at the sqlite3@3.1.13 install script.

npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.



npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:

npm ERR!     /Users/luis/.npm/_logs/2018-03-09T09_16_15_084Z-debug.log
```

Comment: Are you installing `sqlite3` npm package or the database ?

Comment: I'm installing npm package

Comment: can you provide the installation command here...

Answer (score 7):

The solution worked for me is, I have resolved by running `npm cache clean --force` and `npm install sqlite3 --build-from-source --unsafe-perm` command individually.

This issue generally occurs because of authorization error on https://mapbox-node-binary.s3.amazonaws.com/sqlite3/v3.1.11/node-v59-win32-x64.tar.gz

Hope that work for you.

Comment: Or you may update version of `sqlite3` from ^3 to ^4.